getting iOS battery level with battery_info and battery_plus packages
I am trying to use both battery_info and battery_plus packages. For iOS i know there is limitation that we can only get battery percentage and battery state (either charging or discharging etc.). Previously it was working fine in iOS. I was able to see the battery percentage but few days before i don't know either there is some package change or apple restrictions, both packages are giving wrong and weird battery percentage. Like alway in the multiple of 5.
Below is the simple code i am using for getting battery percentage.
  try {
      IosBatteryInfo? batteryInfo = await batteryInfoPlugin.iosBatteryInfo;

      final int batteryLevel =  batteryInfo!.batteryLevel!;
      print("IOS battery level is $batteryLevel");
      batteryController.currentBatteryPercentage.value = batteryLevel;
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print("Error getting battery level: ${e.message}");
    }

ps: This issue is only happening for iOS. for android it is working fine. Also, it was working fine one week before but giving these weird and wrong values now.
I am trying to get the battery percentage in iOS but not getting right battery percentage.
